# Crittercism Weak SSL Cipher Suites are Supported and Lack of Certificate Pinning

Tags: react-native, encryption, crittercism, certificate-pinning

Our security team has performed a security scan on our mobile application and found the following vulnerabilities:

```
Vulnerability Name: Weak SSL Cipher Suites are Supported
Vulnerability Type: attWeakCipherSuites
Calling Method: com.crittercism.internal.ca.a(com.crittercism.internal.bz):com.crittercism.internal.cb
Method Signature: javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters.setCipherSuites(java.lang.String[]):void
Location: (Unknown)
Issue Validation Parameter - Name: cipherSuites
Issue Validation Parameter - Value: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

---

```
Vulnerability Name: Lack of Certificate Pinning
Vulnerability Type: attSSLCertificatePinning
Calling Method: com.crittercism.internal.ca.a(com.crittercism.internal.bz):com.crittercism.internal.cb
Method Signature: java.net.URL.openConnection():java.net.URLConnection
Location: (Unknown)
Issue Validation Parameter - Name: this
Issue Validation Parameter - Value: https://5-8-10-android.appload.ingest.crittercism.com/v0/config
```

Can someone help me resolve the issues above?

> Platform: Android
>   Framework: React-native

Comment: What site or host are you connecting to with SSL? Just your own or other sites? How can we possibly know what the nameless security found specifically objectionable? I would guess that it's the CBC ciphersuites but I can't be sure. Get rid of those ciphersuites and see if it makes the tool happy. As for certificate pinning, use a search engine to find many excellent resources, it's too broad of a question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

## Your Questions

### First question

> Vulnerability Name: Weak SSL Cipher Suites are Supported
>   Vulnerability Type: attWeakCipherSuites

You need to pass only the latest recommended ciphers suites and you can read what ones are in the [Mozilla site](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS).

Currently the most secure ones are the ones recommended for [Modern Compatibility](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Modern_compatibility)

```
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
```

### Second question

> Vulnerability Name: Lack of Certificate Pinning
>   Vulnerability Type: attSSLCertificatePinning

Once you are using React Native you may want to try the [react-native-cert-pinner](https://github.com/approov/react-native-cert-pinner) package:

> This package manages TLS certificate pinning in react-native for Android and iOS.

You should read the README of the package for the detailed instructions, but as a quick start, this may work:

```
npm install react-native-cert-pinner --save
```

followed by an automated installation:

```
react-native link react-native-cert-pinner
```

Otherwise you should try, from the README, the [manual installation](https://github.com/approov/react-native-cert-pinner#android) for Android.

## Going the Extra Mile

If you want to understand why you should be using Certificate Pinning, you can read [this blog post](https://blog.approov.io/securing-https-with-certificate-pinning-on-android) on these 2 sections:

#### What is Certificate Pinning?

It will briefly explain what it is and how it works in an high level, and what to pin.

> Certificate pinning is the mechanism of associating a domain name with an expected SSL/TLS certificate, technically and more accurately known as an X.509 certificate.

#### Why do we need Certificate Pinning?

Here it explains why is needed to be used in order to prevent trust based assumptions and to protect against use in hostile environments.

> While https gives you confidentiality, integrity and authenticity in the communication channel between the mobile app and the API server, certificate pinning will protect this same guarantees from being broken.